# how to use ComplexType in Fluent - CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration

In my project I want Log some Event for each Table   like below events :

```
CreatedOn, CreatdBy,IsDeleted,DeletedBy,DeletedOn
```

for do this I create a ComplexType like this :

```
 [ComplexType]
public class Log
{
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatorId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public User DeletedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid? DeletedUserId { get; set; }

}
```

}

and use in another Table like this :

```
 public class StoreMaster
{
//some fields
public virtual Log Log { get; set; }
}
```

and I have this Fluent like this :

```
 HasRequired(row => row.Log.CreatedBy).WithMany(row => row.StoreMasters).HasForeignKey(row => row.Log.CreatorId).WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

when run Project I getting this error :

> The expression 'row => row.Log.CreatedBy' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid what you are trying to achieve is not possible. First thing is complex type *can only contain primitives properties*, so you can't declare navigation properties there. Second thing is the scalar properties you define in your complex type can't be used in the definition of a relationship.The parent object where you declare your complex type as property is the only who can manage it.